# You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. within App.jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is the content of my App.jsx. Note when I remove the React router piece and add the PDPContent component directly within JSX It renders just fine.

```
    import React, { Suspense, useState } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import PDPContent from "./PDPContent";
    import "./index.scss";
    const Header = React.lazy(() => import("home/Header"));
    const Footer = React.lazy(() => import("home/Footer"));
    
    import SafeComponent from "./SafeComponent";
    
    const App = () => (
      <Router>
        <div className="text-3xl mx-auto max-w-6xl">
          <SafeComponent>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
              <Header />
            </Suspense>
          </SafeComponent>
          <div className="my-10">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/product/:id" component={PDPContent} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
            <Footer />
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

This is the content of my PDPContent.jsx. Note when I remove useParams below and hard code the value of the product id as 10,  it works just fine.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getProductById, currency } from "home/products";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function PDPContent() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      getProductById(id).then((product) => {
        setProduct(product);
      });
    } else {
      setProduct(null);
    }
  }, [id]);
  console.log("Id is ");
  console.log(id);
  if (!product) return null;
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-5">
      <div>
        <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="flex">
          <h1 className="font-bold text-3xl flex-grow">{product.name}</h1>
          <div className="font-bold text-3xl flex-end">
            {currency.format(product.price)}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-10">{product.description}</div>
        <div className="mt-10">{product.longDescription}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving import of useParams in PDP file up in the import hierarchy?

Comment: did.  Didn't work. :-(

Comment: Try changing `if (!product) return null;` to `if (!product) return <></>;`.

Comment: Which version of `react-router-dom` are you using?